# Using devise "rememberable" without cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, cookies, file-upload, devise

I have a working Rails site that uses [devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to manage users.  For session management, I am using devise's [rememberable](http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Rememberable) strategy, which stores and retrieves encrypted authentication information from a user's cookie.

I'm implementing a multi-photo upload widget that uses flash.  Flash does not support sending cookies along with requests.  This is a problem with multiple multi-upload flash+javascript libraries, so fixing this shortcoming is probably not feasible.

So my question is: can I successfully authenticate to devise/rememberable *without using cookies*?  And if so, how?

#### More details

Devise/rememberable depends on the value of `remember_token` within the cookie.  If I could fool Rails into thinking that the value was supplied as a cookie (e.g. `request.cookies['remember_token'] = '...'`), my problem would be solved.  Devise/rememberable would find the correct value there, unpack it, and successfully authenticate.  However, the `request.cookies` hash is apparently read-only.  Writing to the hash is silently ignored.  Example (debug console from an incoming POST request):

```
>> request.cookies['remember_token'] = 'a string'
=> "a string"
>> request.cookies['remember_token']
=> nil
>> request.cookies
=> {}
```

I'm using (or trying to use) the [FancyUpload v3](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/) widget.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar but different - a way to set a cookie like remember_token but for non-remember-me logins, to make inter-app login sharing easier.  Bumping your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about overriding Devise slightly?

Based on Devise 1.2.rc something like this should work:

```
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class Rememberable
      def remember_cookie
        # your code to get the hashed value from the request
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you could add a new (subclassed) strategy:

```
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class RememberableParameter < Rememberable
      def remember_cookie
        # your code to get the hashed value from the request
      end
    end
  end
end
Warden::Strategies.add(:rememberable_parameter, Devise::Strategies::Rememberable)
```

Or, look into Token Authenticatable:

> Token Authenticatable: signs in a user based on an authentication token (also known as
>   "single access token"). The token can be given both through query string or
>   HTTP Basic Authentication

There's more about it here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/token_authenticatable.rb

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I didn't want to override Devise because of source control management issues, but the token authenticatable strategy worked great.  Now I just need to turn off token-based authentication for all other actions. :-)  Thanks for your help.