# Toggling Devise authentication modules per controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have a Rails site that uses [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication.  I have one page (`PhotosController#create`) that needs to authenticate users without cookies.  I'm doing this with the `:token_authenticatable` module of Devise, which authenticates a user if the supplied token matches the token stored on the server side.  (See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071737) if you're curious.)

It's good policy to expire or change the token after the action is complete.  This prevents an attacker from sniffing the token and using it to successfully authenticate as the user.  However, in my case, I can't expire or change the token because the client-side photo uploader uploads multiple photos, each resulting in a separate POST to `PhotosController#create`.  So if I expire the token after a successful create, the second, third, etc. uploads will fail.

Devise modules are specified at the model level (e.g. the `User` model).  I need more granularity than this.

My question is, how do I enable the `:token_authenticatable` module **only** for a single action of a single controller?  Or, equivalently, how do I disable the `:token_authenticatable` module for all controllers and actions **except** for one action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the developer of one devise plugin (devise_rpx_connectable) I'm happy to answer your question.

TokenAuthenticatable is one Devise strategy, you can read its code here :

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/token_authenticatable.rb

As you can see, each devise strategy has a valid? and/or valid_request? method that is called to determine if the strategy should be enabled. So you can easily override this strategy for your needs, or you can also only override the valid_request? method. Just load this kind of code in an initializer (AFTER devise is loaded of course) :

```
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class TokenAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
      private
      def valid_request?
        params[:controller] == "photos" && params[:action] == "create"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I haven't tested this, I don't know if that works out of the box but I hope you see the point, if that doesn't work, use a debugger, or write your own Devise Strategy (see my plugin, it's easy to understand), etc.

Moreover, when you use this strategy, the user will be stored in session unless you use the stateless_token option, see :
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/token_authenticatable.rb#L27

Comment: Hi slainer68, thanks for the reply. That approach worked for me in general, but I had to do some significant tweaking to get it to work. My eventual solution is logged as a separate answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in an initializer

```
require 'devise/strategies/base'
require 'devise/strategies/token_authenticatable'
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class TokenAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
      private
      def valid_request?
        params[:controller] == "photos" && params[:action] == "create"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

slainer68's approach is good, but it didn't work for me as-is, so I'll add my eventual solution here.

In `config/initializers/devise.rb`, which already had a `Devise.setup do |config| ... end` block, I prepended the following:

```
Warden::Strategies.add(:my_token_authenticatable, Devise::Strategies::TokenAuth
  def valid?
    mapping.to.respond_to?(:authenticate_with_token) && authentication_token(scope).present? && params[:controller] == 'photos' && params[:action] == 'create'
  end
end
```

I also added this to the `Devise.setup` block:

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies.unshift :my_token_authenticatable
end
```

It would have been better to simply update the existing `:token_authenticatable` strategy, but that wasn't loaded into Warden by the time this code was executed.  As a result of having to use a strategy with a different name, I had to duplicate some methods and class methods from `Devise::Strategies::TokenAuthenticatable`, including:

- `reset_authentication_token`
- `reset_authentication_token!`
- `self.authenticate_with_token(attributes)`
- `self.token_authentication_key`
- `valid_authentication_token?(incoming_auth_token)`
- `self.find_for_token_authentication(token)`

I also had to remove :token_authenticatable from the `devise` line at the top of the User model.

I also took slainer68's advice and added `:stateless_token => false` to the options for `devise_for` in `config/routes.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution can be found here: [Devise allow token authentication on single controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081338/devise-allow-token-authentication-on-single-controller-action/11081734#11081734) My apologies, but I don't know how to mark the question as a possible repeat of, etc. The mentioned solution worked for me using rails 3.2.7.

In summary, it doesn't use `def valid_request?` which is private and cannot be called directly from a class outside. (check the base code for a strategy at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb#L15 ) Therefore, not exactly the best place to override. Instead, you should use `valid?` and have something like this:

```
require 'devise/strategies/base'
require 'devise/strategies/token_authenticatable'
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class TokenAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
      def valid?
        super && params[:controller] == "your controller" && params[:action] == "your action"
      end
    end
  end
end
```