# Overriding methods in strategies in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

This question:

[Toggling Devise authentication modules per controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098563/toggling-devise-authentication-modules-per-controller-action?tab=votes#tab-top)

Has an a simple answer that indicates you should be able to override a method in the Devise Strategy, and the initial poster of the question described how he couldn't get the override to work but added a whole new strategy.

My question is: how do you get the override to work?  It should be doable, but I haven't been able to figure it out.