# Devise allow token authentication on single controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have an webapplication that uses devise database authentication for all the controllers, however I want to have one controller action where authentication is also done using a token. Can i use devise for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Devise strategies have a `valid?` method that is called to determine if the strategy should be enabled. This allows you to control available auth strategies on a per controller/action basis.

Put this in an initializer:

```
require 'devise/strategies/base'
require 'devise/strategies/token_authenticatable'
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class TokenAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
      def valid?
        super && params[:controller] == "your controller" && params[:action] == "your action"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: I'll try this when i get home and let you know... But thanks, sounds just like what i need.

Comment: but you need to set up your user model as  token authenticable of course

Comment: It is... Token Authentication is working, but just for every controller / action... I want to limit it to a certain controller#action

Comment: Can this be what i'm looking for (valid_params_request?)? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/token_authenticatable.rb

Comment: valid? doesnt work... valid_request on Class Authenticatable works, however, then the controller action doesnt work anymore [] Nil Class error...

Comment: Wait... i got it :); Remove the private from your code and i'll accept the answer :)